Unresolved Reference Error in gradle file while adding retrofit and gson dependencies
I am facing errors while adding implementation in gradle file in android studio for retrofit api and gson I am a complete newbie in this please help me.
Gradle File
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.api"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.api"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation(com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0)
    implementation(com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0)
}


Error messages
Error Messages
I am facing errors while adding implementation in gradle file in android studio for retrofit api and gson I am a complete newbie in this please help me.

I have the same problem. I cannot set retrofit2 as a dependency (Unresolved reference: retrofit2)

I solved it by upgrading my Android Studio to version Iguana. Which version are you using right now?
